# Using Tasks, "Index out of Range" and IsCompleted prematurely returning true

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm trying to test my understanding of (and learn about) tasks in "Windows Store" C#.  I made a multi-tasking app that contains several progress bars and simulated tasks that count to 100 over varying periods of time.  It will eventually be the basis for a mutlti-threaded file parser.

I have a task-handling task "parseFiles" that loops through a queued list of tasks until they are all complete by checking a counter.

Anyways, while this program is running, I randomly get first chance exceptions of the index out of range variety in the task handling for loop of the "parseFiles" task.  The loop counter, i, somehow gets set as a value higher than possible, i.e. 3 even though the for loop clearly only sets i to a maximum of 2.

The other strange thing that happens is that the "parsing" tasks in parsers[] sometimes return a true value for IsCompleted even though they haven't started.

Any ideas on what is causing these strange bugs?  Am I doing something wrong here?

I'd also gladly accept any advice on a more robust or easier way of queuing and handling the parsing tasks since it would probably fix the two bugs.

Here's the code:

```
namespace TaskTest
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    testFile[] fileList;
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        fileList = new testFile[10];
        for(int j=0; j<10; j++){
            fileList[j] = new testFile();
        }
    }

    private static void parseFile(testFile file, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        progress.Report(0);
        file.parse(progress);
    }

    public Task parseFiles(IProgress<int>[] progresses) {
        int nParsers = 3;
        int nParsers = 3;
        if (nParsers > fileList.Length)
        {
            nParsers = fileList.Length;
        }
        Task[] parsers = new Task[nParsers];
        Boolean parseCompleted = false;

        Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //Do the parsing
                int fileCounter = -1;
                Boolean startedLast = false;
                Boolean[] finalTasksDone = new Boolean[nParsers];
                while (!parseCompleted)
                {

                    for(int i=0; i<=(nParsers - 1); i++){
                        if (!startedLast && (parsers[i] == null || parsers[i].IsCompleted))
                        {
                            fileCounter++;
                            Debug.WriteLine("Task " + i + " completed. Starting new Task " + i + " to parse file #" + fileCounter);
                            if (fileCounter == fileList.Length - 1) { startedLast = true; }
                            Action<testFile, Progress<int>> parseAction = parseFile;
                            parsers[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => parseFile(fileList[fileCounter], progresses[i]));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (startedLast && parsers[i].IsCompleted)
                            {
                                finalTasksDone[i] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    int finishedCounter = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i <= (nParsers - 1); i++)
                    {
                        if (finalTasksDone[i])
                        {
                            finishedCounter++;
                        }
                    }
                    if (finishedCounter >= nParsers)
                    {
                        parseCompleted = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        return null;
    }


    public class testFile{

        public async void parse(IProgress<int> progress){
            Random random = new Random();
            int simDelay = 1;
            int simFileLength = random.Next(50, 100);
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting file with length: " + simFileLength);
            for(int j=0; j<simFileLength; j++){
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(simDelay));
                int percentProgress = (int) (((double) j/ (double) simFileLength) * 100);
                progress.Report(percentProgress);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IProgress<int>[] progresses = new Progress<int>[3];
        progresses[0] = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress1);
        progresses[1] = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress2);
        progresses[2] = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress3);
        parseFiles(progresses);
    }
    private void ReportProgress1(int value)
    {
        pBar1.Value = value;
    }
    private void ReportProgress2(int value)
    {
        pBar2.Value = value;
    }
    private void ReportProgress3(int value)
    {
        pBar3.Value = value;
    }

}


}
```

Here's a log from a typical run.
According to this, most of the tasks don't even get started before they return true on IsCompleted.

```
Task 0 completed. Starting new Task 0 to parse file #0
Task 1 completed. Starting new Task 1 to parse file #1
Task 2 completed. Starting new Task 2 to parse file #2
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in TaskTest.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in  TaskTest.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Task 1 completed. Starting new Task 1 to parse file #3
Task 2 completed. Starting new Task 2 to parse file #4
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in TaskTest.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Starting file with length: 73
Starting file with length: 83
Task 2 completed. Starting new Task 2 to parse file #5
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in TaskTest.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Task 2 completed. Starting new Task 2 to parse file #6
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in TaskTest.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Task 1 completed. Starting new Task 1 to parse file #7
Task 2 completed. Starting new Task 2 to parse file #8
Starting file with length: 78
Task 1 completed. Starting new Task 1 to parse file #9
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in TaskTest.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in TaskTest.exe
Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

The program '[7372] TaskTest.exe' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Comment: If you are asking about tasks/multi-threading, remove unrelated/unnecessary parts from your code and ask a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: The only part of your question that can be answered is "am I doing something wrong here", and the answer is "probably yes". You need to narrow down the scope of this question a lot before it becomes practical for anyone else to help you. For instance, *where* do you get that exception?

Comment: I really can't simplify the code any more considering I have no idea what the source of the exception or the other bug is.  This is the simplified version.

The exception occurs on the only line in which the indicated index is used to access an array - in the for loop of the parseFiles task.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem I see with this code is that `parseFiles()` will exit prematurely in many cases.  Suppose parser 0 has completed and parsers 1 and 2 still have a long way to go, when you've started all the files so `startedLast` is true.  Now, the `while (!parseCompleted)` loop will execute, and within the for loop, will find parser 0 has completed and increment `lastTasksCount` to 1.  Now, the `while (!parseCompleted)` loop executes again, and within the for loop, again finds that parser 0 is completed, and increments `lastTasksCount` to 2.  This happens one more time, `lastTasksCount` is incremented to 3, `parseCompleted` is set to true, and the method exits, all while parser 1 and parser 2 are still working.  I think maybe if you fix this bug, the rest of the symptoms go away - or change if another bug is exposed.

With regard to your specific symptoms, you don't say what specific symptom you think is the result of IsComplete() returning true when the task isn't started yet.  There are two things that could be misleading in this respect.  One is the above exiting from the `parseFiles` when some tasks are still in progress.  The other is that the debug statement that starts with "Task X completed" will print at the beginning when parser X doesn't exist yet, just before the parser X slot is filled for the first time.  The resulting debug statement could be a bit misleading.

I don't really see a way for `i` to go out of bounds, though if the number of files is less than the number of parsers, there will be a null pointer access.  For example, if there is one file and two parsers, the first time through the `for` loop a parser 0 will be created for the file, startedLast will be set to true, and then the next time through the `for` loop the test `if (startedLast && parsers[1].IsCompleted)` will be executed while parsers[1] is still null.  This will not cause a problem with the constants as written, however, since you have 10 files which is greater than 3, the number of parsers you have.

Again, I would fix the first bug I mentioned in the first paragraph, and possibly the bug that occurs when the number of parsers exceeds the number of files, and see if that clears up your problems.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the details.
I hadn't thought the startedLast thing through, clearly. I added a for loop and a boolean array to check each of the final parsers.

The problem is before that, though.  These simulated tasks should be taking a minute each and they're not.  That's what I mean by IsCompleted returning true prematurely.  In the parsing method of the file object, I have a debug output to indicate that the delay loop is executing. It doesn't.

The integer i really is going out of bounds, too.  I turned on breaking for the exception and i is somehow incrementing to 3.

Comment: Can you update the code in the question, and also include the logs from a typical run with the updated code?